# How to use Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML()) to only target a field with a specific “attribute-id”?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

My XML

```
<custom-attributes>
  <custom-attribute attribute-id="notNeededField">Value1</custom-attribute>
  <custom-attribute attribute-id="neededField">Value2</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
```

What I am trying to do is only get the value of the custom-attribute where the attribute-id is "neededField". All other attribute-ids aren't needed for this operation and I don't want to iterate over each custom-attribute since there are an unknown number and I only need a specific one.

My code

```
SET @myVar = Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@xml, "/custom-attributes/custom-attribute", 0), 2), "Value")
```

This works when the attribute-id "neededField" is the second custom-attribute but that's not always the case.

I found a similar question here: [How to use BuildRowSetFromXML with an "attribute-id" in SFMC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253170/how-to-use-buildrowsetfromxml-with-an-attribute-id-in-sfmc) but it deals with getting each attribute-id, not targeting a specific one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference node attributes like this using XPATH 1.0 syntax:

```ampscript
if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@XML, '/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="neededField"]')) > 0 then

   set @neededField= Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@XML, '/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="neededField"]',0),1), 'Value')

endif
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!

Answer (score -2):

i am using the same logic but I get an error
[How to use Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML()) to fetch a field with a specific attribute-id from XML](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/379882/how-to-use-fieldrowbuildrowsetfromxml-to-fetch-a-field-with-a-specific-attr)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/178373)