# How to use Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML()) to fetch a field with a specific attribute-id from XML

Tags: marketing-cloud, trigger, ampscript, api, xml

Issue
From the attached XML i am traying to read the value of "vertex_retail_delivery_fee" with below
code.

```xml
<custom-attribute attribute-id="vertex_retail_delivery_fee">0.27</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="vertex_retail_delivery_fee_deducted_from_total_tax">5.07</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="vertex_taxation_details">
```

Goal is to display the value if the xml has the attribute else it should be display "0.00" the below logic is throwing me error.

> An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a RowCount function
> call. See inner exception for details. xml parameter is invalid.
> Function: BuildRowsetFromXML(@XML,
> 'custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="vertex_retail_delivery_fee"]')

Code:

```ampscript
if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@XML, '/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="vertex_retail_delivery_fee"]')) > 0 
then
set @RetailFee= Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@XML, '/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="vertex_retail_delivery_fee"]',0),1), 'Value'),'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this and it worked:

```
%%[
  SET @xml = ATTRIBUTEVALUE('xml')
  SET @rs = BuildRowSetFromXML(@xml, '/order/custom-attributes/custom-attribute', 0)
  SET @rc = ROWCOUNT(@rs)
  IF ROWCOUNT(@rs) > 0 THEN
    FOR @i = 1 to @rc DO
      SET @nodepath = CONCAT("/order/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[", @i, "]/")
      SET @attr = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath, "@attribute-id"),0),1),'Value')
      IF @attr == "vertex_retail_delivery_fee" THEN
        SET @value = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath, "text()"),0),1),'Value')
      ENDIF
    NEXT
  ENDIF
]%%
<hr>
value ==== %%=v(@value)=%%
<hr>
```

Comment: This Worked and was really helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to find all the custom-attribute nodes, loop through each of them to fetch the attribute-id value and match it with 'vertex_retail_delivery_fee' and get its value to get the delivery fee value. Below is a sample code.

```ampscript
    %%[
      var @xml
      set @xml = ""
      set @xml = concat(@xml, '<custom-attributes>')
      set @xml = concat(@xml, ' <custom-attribute attribute-id="vertex_retail_delivery_fee">0.27</custom-attribute>')
      set @xml = concat(@xml, '    <custom-attribute attribute-id="vertex_retail_delivery_fee_deducted_from_total_tax">5.07</custom-attribute>')
      set @xml = concat(@xml, '    <custom-attribute attribute-id="vertex_taxation_details"/>')
      set @xml = concat(@xml, '</custom-attributes>')
      
      //OutputLine(concat('<br>XML value = ' , @xml))
    
      set @rowCount = rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml, '/custom-attributes/custom-attribute'))
    
      //OutputLine(concat('<br>Number of custom-attribute rows = ' , @rowCount))
    
      if @rowCount > 0 then 
      for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
        set @nodePathAttributeId = concat('/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[',@i,']/@attribute-id')
        set @attributeId= Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@XML, @nodePathAttributeId,0),1), 'Value')
        //OutputLine(concat('<br>attributeId = ', @attributeId))
        if @attributeId == "vertex_retail_delivery_fee" then 
          //OutputLine(concat('<br>Found vertex_retail_delivery_fee'))
          set @nodePathForVal = concat('/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[',@i,']')
          set @val= Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@XML, @nodePathForVal,0),1), 'Value')
          OutputLine(concat('<br>vertex_retail_delivery_fee Value = ' ,@val))
        endif
       next @i
      endif
    
      
    ]%%
```